# What is the "." folder in my directory and where is it coming from?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, directory

Whenever I do the `ll -a -tr` command in the current directory, I sometimes find a directory called "." or ".." listed. The randomly created "." directory has a size.

So clearly, if I do `cd .`, it will just keep me in the current directory. If I do `vi .`, it also shows what is in the current directory, but not necessarily the "." folder.

Here is an example of what I would see after doing `ll -a -tr`:

```
[user folder_name]$ ll -a -tr
drwxr-xr-x 5 user     4096 Jul 19 19:17 ..  <--- what is this and where did it come from?
drwxr-xr-x 2 user     4096 Jul 21 10:31 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user     400  Aug  9 15:31 code.tcl
drwxr-xr-x 2 user    36864 Aug 10 11:04 Another_Folder
drwxr-xr-x 8 user     4096 Aug 10 11:07 .   <--- what is this and where did it come from?
```

Are the two arrows pointing to the ".." and "." related to an operation in bash or are they something else? If they are something else, what are they?

Comment: I made an update to my answer

Comment: Firstly this question doesn't belong here as it has nothing to do with programming.  Secondly I can't imagine any situation in a unix/linux type of OS where you *don't* get the "." .... it's the current directory.

Comment: 1. If the "." found in a directory is relevant to the "." operation, then it is relevant to programming because "." is a command used in bash scripting. 2. Even if "." is suppose to exist in every directory, that comment does not address the question as to what the "." is/

Answer (score 1):

The dot (.) hard link is part of the directory entry and is needed to support the path navigation/reference.

It is used for relative paths that refer to a location relative to a current directory. Relative paths make use of two special symbols, a dot (`.`) and a double-dot (`..`), which translate into the current directory and the parent directory. Double dots are used for moving up in the hierarchy. A single dot represents the current directory itself.

Let put it with an example:

if you are in `/home/Downloads` and you type in a terminal `ls -a` it will shows:

```
.  ..   programs  stuff
```

and `ls -a` in `/home/Desktop`

```
.  ..  somefile
```

now, imagine you want to copy `somefile` from `/home/Desktop` into `/home/Downloads` and you are in the path `/home/Downloads`, you could use the short names:

```
/home/Downloads $ cp ../Desktop/file ./
```

so, in this example:

"`..`" : is the `/home` directory

"`.`" : is the /home/Downloads directory

Comment: think you mean "previous" not "previews", just for clarification purposes

Comment: @jmoon totally right, thanks a lot, the corrector... haha

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your answer. Can you further clarify your answer?

Comment: @Omneya of course, I will try again

Comment: @Omneya I made an update to my answer, I hope now you can now what this is all about :)

Comment: @jmoon I made an update to my answer, thanks for your comments :)

Comment: @Alexey Zagalsky thanks a lot for the improve! that's really great now, thanks!

Comment: @DamianLattenero I think there may be some confusion about what I am asking. So, I found a   file called `.` in my current directory. I don't understand why it was created. Some of my directories have `.` while others do not. I appreciate your answer, but I am asking more about `.` (the random directory created), not the directory operator `.` I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `.` is not an operator; it is an entry in the current directory that the file system itself ensures is created at the time the directory is created. Likewise for `..`: it is a real directory entry created to represent the parent of the directory.

Comment: @chepner thanks for beeing the spot of light here, you are the best :)